# Can I hide the part of long lines that exceeds the visual line?

Tags: code-folding, line-truncation

Is it possible to hide the part of long lines that exceeds the visual line rather than wrapping it into further visual lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Line Truncation`

> As an alternative to continuation (*note Continuation Lines::), Emacs
>   can display long lines by “truncation”.  This means that all the
>   characters that do not fit in the width of the screen or window do not
>   appear at all.  On graphical displays, a small straight arrow in the
>   fringe indicates truncation at either end of the line.  On text
>   terminals, this is indicated with `$` signs in the rightmost and/or
>   leftmost columns.
>
> Horizontal scrolling automatically causes line truncation (*note
>   Horizontal Scrolling::).  You can explicitly enable line truncation for
>   a particular buffer with the command `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`.  This
>   works by locally changing the variable `truncate-lines`.  If that
>   variable is non-`nil`, long lines are truncated; if it is `nil`, they
>   are continued onto multiple screen lines.  Setting the variable
>   `truncate-lines` in any way makes it local to the current buffer; until
>   that time, the default value, which is normally `nil`, is in effect.
>
> If a split window becomes too narrow, Emacs may automatically enable
>   line truncation.  *Note Split Window::, for the variable
>   `truncate-partial-width-windows` which controls this.